# Curl and Wget returns different response code

Tags: redirect, curl, wget

I am trying to wget a link, this wget works fine on my local machine but it doesn't do so on the server.
i tried to check the response header and i got the following on my local laptop

```
curl -I http://en.cihan.com.tr/rss?user=albawaba\&type=12
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)/Tomcat-5.5
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E65E0CC7CF956F45962FD8571F3AB02A; Path=/
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 80043
Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2012 12:19:26 GMT
Set-Cookie: NSC_fo-sv-bs.djibo.dpn.us=ffffffff092a094245525d5f4f58455e445a4a4229a0;expires=Thu, 29-Mar-2012 12:20:51 GMT;path=/
X-Cache: MISS from Bilal
Connection: close
```

while on the server i got

```
curl -I http://en.cihan.com.tr/rss?user=albawaba\&type=12
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)/Tomcat-5.5
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=CCB29F3789ED06C505436F1289A122D4; Path=/
Location: http://en.cihan.com.tr/rssAlert
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2012 12:11:33 GMT
Set-Cookie: NSC_fo-sv-bs.djibo.dpn.us=ffffffff092a094245525d5f4f58455e445a4a4229a0;expires=Thu, 29-Mar-2012 12:12:58 GMT;path=/
```

**Any idea of why i am getting response 200 on my laptop and 302 on the server for the same link!!?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are redirected to says "You are not authorized to access this page!".

This is little more than a guess but I think that they are doing IP dependent content restriction and your laptop is in an allowed location while your server is not.

I tried the same URL myself and got the 302 redirect from two different places in the UK and one in France.  I got a connection timeout from an Amazon EC2 server.

Oddly, they are using a 302 redirect to the error page rather than simply serving the error page with an appropriate HTTP response code, such as 403 or 401.

Comment: That it is true 100%,,,, i just checked with our clients and found them restricting access to ip of our office only

Answer (score 0):

...because the server responds differently based on the source IP ?

How would we know the answer to something you run on your server ?